# Word meaning "to make more efficient"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I think this question came up in a conversation with a friend...we were discussing how serving lunch could be made more efficient.

> They could ***_*____** the lunch line by doing this or that.

The only word we could think of was "efficienize", but I doubt that's an actual word. Any ideas?

Comment: "efficien[s]ize" is a great example of a word that should be in the english language because it fills a hole not quite filled by alternatives, but people refuse to add it/use it, because it's not "proper" english.

Comment: @Jonathon: What about the accepted answer? That fits it exactly.

Comment: I know you're looking for a single word, but I would just say:  They could make the lunch line more efficient by doing this or that.

Comment: Actually I came up with the exact same question and concluded identically that there really *is* no word for it exactly. I was envisioning a word to mean to make more efficient again: namely, to “re-efficientise” something. So I am coining a new word: to *efficientize* something! You like it?! I guess my second suggestion would be the originally suggested *efficienize*. The other words don’t quite cut it with respect to the intention of the meaning we are trying to portray.

Comment: Another made-up new word is "efficientify." In general, you can add "ify" to any English word to turn that word into a verb.

Comment: I like the word "efficientize" as well and use it all the time myself!  Yes, if a populace invents words because nothing quite gets that meaning, why shouldn't we create new ones?  Merriam Webster added "googling" when we had plenty sufficient "searching."  As others said below, efficient doesn't mean optimal and vice versa.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think that the word you're looking for here is **optimize**:

> From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/optimize): to make as perfect, effective, or functional as possible

Comment: Damn you sirrah! The word is **optimise**! :)

Comment: For me as non-native, 'optimize' has a different meaning. As you say: as effective as possible, whereas the question was *more* effective, not a optimum state. Isn't that something different?

Comment: Optimizing is the process of making something optimal.  So to optimize is to make more efficient.

Comment: Optimizing in this sense is a little casual. Optimum means the best possible. The OPs goal was just to make it better, not necessarily optimal. The last 10% of optimal is often more costly than it is worth. Nonetheless, you are certainly correct that it has come to mean simply "make more effective."

Comment: @bonifaz, agree. Optimize is not precisely correct. Making the lunch line effective does not necessarily mean it will be more efficient (since effective has a broader scope; maybe you make more $ by slowing the line down a bit and allowing for impulse purchase). In this case I'd vote for 'streamline' as it directly infers the efficiency of the line.

Comment: Not to rock the boat, but I disagree. _Optimisation_ is the (usually incremental) process of making something optimal, but when you optimise something it's usually done in discrete steps. So, the process by which something becomes optimal is _optimisation_, but it doesn't have to be optimal until the end of the process.

Comment: Optimize doesn't feel right here but I can't put my finger on why.  I optimize the web site performance.  I optimize the process for washing dishes.  Optimizing the *lunch line* doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: Just because something is efficient doesn't mean it's optimal (and vice-versa). Something being optimal means it is "the most efficient it can be", but it can still be very inefficient. Similarly there are a lot of "efficient" ways to do something but not all of them are optimal (i.e. some are still more efficient then others).

Answer (score 42):

[**Streamline**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/streamline)

1. (transitive) To design and construct the contours of a vehicle etc. so as to offer the least resistance to its flow through a fluid.
2. (transitive, by extension) To simplify or organize a process in order to increase its efficiency.
3. (transitive) To modernise.

Comment: In the context of making a lunch line more efficient, I'd go with this word.

Comment: I'd argue against using this word, as it's been frequently abused as a buzzword.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the word 'improve'?
Seems to fit in quite nicely in the sentence:
"They could **improve** the lunch line by doing this or that."

I think that optimize doesn't quite capture the original intent (and it doesn't sound as good to me):
"They could **optimize** the lunch line by doing this or that."

Comment: I don't think "improve" is specific enough for this request.

Comment: +1 Optimize implies there are no further improvements to be made, whereas improve leaves room for more.

Answer (score 3):

A great word for this is [kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen), a word originating in Japanese production improvement systems. It is not all that common in general English, but in operations and production systems it has become quite a common term.

FYI, it originally was a noun and sometimes an adjective, however, it has transformed in English to be usable as a verb too. "Could you guys kaizen the production line?"

Comment: Is using kaizen as a verb like using ask as a noun?

Comment: @fluffy:  I've only ever seen it as a noun, not a verb.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Do people ask you things, or do they ask you what "the ask" is? (Or were you referring to kaizen? In which case that was exactly my point.)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that "optimize" is close but not exactly the same. To say that a company "optimized its procedures" is not the same as saying that a "company rendered its procedures more efficient", because the latter implies results whereas the former only implies changes made which will hopefully yield results. In the example given by the OP, "optimize" works just fine. But in other scenarios, "render more efficient" or "increase the efficiency of" would give a more accurate meaning.

Answer (score 0):

**Shorten** the lunch line.
**Speed up** the lunch line.

You are talking about making the lunch-serving process more efficient, and your example says you are measuring that by how long (presumably) the queue is.   So. Improving the serving process means reducing the number of people in the line, or the waiting time on it.

**"I'm hungry, dammit.  Send in the operations managers!"**

Operations management is the discipline of business administration concerned with making processes more efficient.  You could read up on it to find out what has been done lately in the area of meal-serving.