# Looking for a word or words meaning to change something so it's more widely used and more efficient to use

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I'm writing a proposal regarding website development work and would like a meaningful name for the proposal. I currently have a system for developing websites that isn't the most efficient and costs a substantial amount for each site. I'm hoping to redevelop my system so that the bulk of the set up effort is automated or more efficient. My intention is to enable use of the system by hundreds of people rather than the dozen or so that are currently using it, without an increase in support needs.

I think something like "Website Generalisation Project" is on the right track, but doesn't really communicate the message I'm looking for. Optimisation isn't really what I'm looking for (it implies no further room for improvement), though "streamlining" might be ok. However, there might be a more suitable word relating to the increase in the number of people using the system.

Related question: [Word meaning "to make more efficient"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43841/word-meaning-to-make-more-efficient)

Comment: Dunno'.

I'd vote to migrate this question to HowToSellIdeas.stackexchange.com but, due to some oversight, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pitarou, I'm not asking about how to sell it, but about which words best describe the project.

Answer (score 2):

One might follow the word *website* (or *webpage*) with *generator, maker, factory, producer, assistant, wizard, assembler,* or *assembly line*.  Examples: *website generator, website wizard*.